# java binding vlc

Tags: java, binding, exception, vlc

I have vlc portable app. in my machine.
When I try to load the lib using this code

```
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(
                  RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:/arun/software_Installations/VLC"
                );

Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
```

it throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libvlc': The specified module could not be found.

at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:169)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:242)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:368)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:353)
at guvi.VLCJ.main(VLCJ.java:18)
```

Comment: are you sure about the path?

Comment: s the path is correct. its a portable version so only the path looks odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should try

```
System.load("C:\\Path\\Of\\libvlc.dll");
```

at least to verify that your library can be loaded. And if not, it may give you useful error messages.

Then, search for the files `libvlc.dll` and `libvlccore.dll` files in to your **VLC** installation and add their path to code that you've written in
`NativeLibrary.addSearchPath()`.

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:/arun/software_Installations/VLC/"); // Make sure the "libvlc.dll" is present in this path.
Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
LibXUtil.initialise();
```

Comment: i am crossing the first hurdle. Now struck up with 64 bit JVM and have to install 32 bit VM in my machine